# Setting the default display name for my model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my Ruby code that sets the default name for my model. [Rubocop](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.27.0/) complains that [Assignment Branch Condition Size](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.27.0/RuboCop/Cop/Metrics/AbcSize) is too high, 21.24/15. How can I improve this?

```
def set_default_display_name
   return unless display_name.blank?
   count = user.credentials.where(type: type).count
   if count == 0
     self.display_name = name
   elsif user.credentials.where(display_name: name).count == 0
     self.display_name = name
   else
     self.display_name = "#{name} #{count + 1}"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notes:

- Conditionals are expressions in Ruby, you can (and, idiomatically, should) move the assignment outside.
- `active_record_relation.count == 0` is ok, but `active_record_relation.empty?` is more declarative.

I'd write:

```
def set_default_display_name
  credentials_by_type = user.credentials.where(type: type)  
  credentials_by_name = user.credentials.where(display_name: type)

  self.display_name = case
  when display_name.present?
    display_name
  when credentials_by_type.empty? && credentials_by_name.empty?
    name
  else
    "#{name} #{credentials_by_type.count + 1}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I only set count as for the the first expression because it is being use in the else condition.

Comment: Maybe `when` should be indented?

Comment: Usually people does not indent it. The ruby-style-guide says no indentation: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Thanks, it still complains but this is an improvement. 18.36/15. Rubocop does complain that when should be indented as deep as case.

Comment: Oh, my. I am not sure how seriously can you take that metric if you can't write such a simple expression :)

Comment: @tokland I was able to refactor you answer to the one below which gets not complaint.

Comment: The || should be && in your answer @tokland

Comment: An AND? But in your original code you have if + if-else. Isn't that an OR?

Comment: That may have been an error. The display name should = :name if there are not connection of that type and there are none with that name.

Comment: Yep, your original code has a bug then. Anyway, updated here.

Answer (score 12):

The method is doing three things:

1. Determining whether or not to set `display_name`.
2. Determining the default display name.
3. Setting `display_name` to the default value.

Each of those adds to the Abc metric. The biggest contributor to the Abc metric is determining the default display name. To me, that also seems like the most logically separate. We can lower the Abc metric by extracting that responsibility to its own method.

```
def set_default_display_name
  self.display_name = default_display_name if display_name.blank?
end

def default_display_name
  credentials_of_type = user.credentials.where(type: type)
  return name if credentials_of_type.none? || user.credentials.where(display_name: name).none?
  "#{name} #{credentials_of_type.count + 1}"
end
```

Extracting `default_display_name` makes it slightly simpler to test the default display name logic. You could also use that logic elsewhere, e.g., a UI could show the current display name and ask if they want to reset it to the default display name.

At this point, I'd question whether `set_default_display_name` is necessary or if it could be inlined.

---

Another option, is to keep your code as is and modify your .rubocop.yml file to increase the threshold of the Abc metric, or disable it entirely. The Abc metric is all about code size, not complexity. Theoretically, bugs increase with code size. You'd have to determine if this low of a threshold makes it easier to mask bugs. (Based on an earlier thread, the answer is probably, "yes", since your original code seems to have a bug. I retained the functionality of your original code in this example.)

--- **Addendum** ---

@ramonrails makes a good point in the comments. I'm usually fine with `return` guard clauses at the top of ruby methods. However, I agree that having a `return` in the middle of this method is not ideal.

This answer was only addressing the ABC question. If this were my code, I'd extract the credentials logic completely from this "view" code.

Something like:

```
def default_display_name(type_credentials)
  type_credentials.any? ? "#{name} #{type_credentials.count + 1}" : name
end
```

We're far afield from the question at that point though.

Comment: This solution should be the accepted answer as is way more readable and really follows the spirit of clean code.

Comment: Abc metric provided the "ah ha!" moment for me. excellent answer

Comment: Two return points in a 3-line code does not seem to be a good ruby practice.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, you can flip just the conditional: `display_name` will be set to `name` is *either* of the counts is zero. So that's an OR clause on the counts being zero, rather than an AND clause on the counts being non-zero.

So that plus `||=` and a `begin..end` will let you do:

```
def set_default_display_name
  self.display_name ||= begin
    credentials_by_type = user.credentials.where(type: type).count
    credentials_by_name = user.credentials.where(display_name: name).count

    if credentials_by_type.zero? || credentials_by_name.zero?
      self.display_name = "#{name} #{credentials_by_type + 1}"
    else
      self.display_name = name
    end
  end
end
```

I'm assuming here, that `blank?` is checking for `nil` specifically, so you can use `||=`. However, if `display_name` can be an empty string that won't work. In that case, I'd personally keep the early return you have now.

```
def set_default_display_name
  return unless self.display_name.blank?
  credentials_by_type = user.credentials.where(type: type).count
  credentials_by_name = user.credentials.where(display_name: name).count

  if credentials_by_type.zero? || credentials_by_name.zero?
    self.display_name = "#{name} #{credentials_by_type + 1}"
  else
    self.display_name = name
  end
end
```

I don't know what Rubocop will think of either of these solutions, though.

Comment: .display_name can be an empty string so the early return would likely be best

Answer (score 0):

**Read the comments** in the code for an explanation. This is the code of the selected answer, more optimized/DRY.

```
def set_default_display_name

  # - 'count' takes less memory, faster execution than 'where' results
  #
  by_type = user.credentials.where(type: type).count
  by_name = user.credentials.where(display_name: type).count

  self.display_name ||= ((by_type + by_name) == 0 ? name : "#{name} #{by_type + 1}")
end
```

**update 1 (2016-09-08):** Reference code removed from comments. Now the comments explain only the optimizations to the selected answer.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @Mast The comments seem to be embedded in the code here. It's not ideal though. In a way this could be a comment (or multiple) to the existing answer, but right now this is an answer (it's not a very good answer, but it is an answer)

Comment: I'd recommend reducing the number of commented lines in this answer. It has potential, but for now I am definitely downvoting.

Comment: @Mast This is not an alternate solution, just more optimized code for the selected answer. That is why the code from the selected answer is also put in comments as a reference.

Comment: @SimonForsberg reference code is now gone from the comments. Only relevant explanation of changes remain. You may read the whole answer again if you like.

Comment: I removed my downvote but I would recommend not putting your explanation of changes within the code block. Answers are better that way.

Comment: I fully agree with @SimonForsberg. Downvote removed. Keep this in mind for future answers. Recommended reading: [How do I write a good answer?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Mast, answer updated even more. I hope this suits. Thank you for sharing the link. I will definitely go through that.